# Eventos con listas desplegables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, html-select

Cómo lograr que ocurra un “evento” cuando se elige una opción del `select` `name="SistemasOperativos"` y a partir de este `select` mostrar otra lista.
 es decir: `name="ClasificacionWvista"` , `name="ClasificacionW7"` o `name="ClasificacionWXp"`

```
<select name="SistemasOperativos" size=9 id="OS" >
   <option selected value="0"> Elige una opción </option>
       <optgroup label="Microsoft"> 
       <option value="1">Windows Vista</option> 
       <option value="2">Windows 7</option> 
       <option value="3">Windows XP</option> 
   </optgroup> 

</select>


<select name="ClasificacionWvista" size=9 id="Vista">
   <option selected value="0"> Elige una opción </option>
       <optgroup label="Microsoft"> 
       <option value="1">Windows Vista Starter</option> 
       <option value="2">Windows Vista Home Basic</option> 
       <option value="3">Windows Vista Home Premium</option>
       <option value="1">Windows Vista Business</option> 
       <option value="2">Windows Vista Ultimate</option> 
       <option value="3">Windows Vista Enterprise</option> 
   </optgroup> 
</select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<select name="ClasificacionW7" size=9 id="W7">
   <option selected value="0"> Elige una opción </option>
       <optgroup label="Microsoft"> 
       <option value="1">Starter</option> 
       <option value="2">Home Basic</option> 
       <option value="3">Professiona</option>
       <option value="2">Ultimate</option> 
       <option value="3">Enterprise</option> 
   </optgroup> 
</select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<select name="ClasificacionWXp" size=9 id="Wxp">
   <option selected value="0"> Elige una opción </option>
       <optgroup label="Microsoft"> 
       <option value="1">Windows XP Media Center</option> 
       <option value="2">Windows XP Tablet PC Edition</option> 
       <option value="3">Windows XP Starter</option>
       <option value="2">Windows XP Home Edition</option> 
       <option value="3">Windows XP Professional</option> 
   </optgroup> 
</select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Falta algo de información: ¿cómo se va a cargar la segunda select? ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento y con qué fallos/dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las tantas formas en que puedes hacer lo que requieres es mostrar/ocultar los grupos dependiendo el primer item seleccionado.

**Ejemplo con JavaScript nativo:**

```js
var SistemasOperativos = document.querySelector("#SistemasOperativos");
var ClasificacionWvista = document.querySelector("#ClasificacionWvista");

SistemasOperativos.addEventListener('change', function(){
  var valor = this.value;
  
  var grupos = ClasificacionWvista.querySelector("optgroup");
  grupos.style.display = 'none';
  
  var grupo = document.querySelector("#grupo_" + valor);
  grupo.style.display = 'block';
})
```

```css
#ClasificacionWvista optgroup{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<select name="SistemasOperativos" id="SistemasOperativos" size=9 id="OS" >
   <option selected value="0"> Elige una opción </option>
       <optgroup label="Microsoft"> 
       <option value="1">Windows Vista</option> 
       <option value="2">Windows 7</option> 
       <option value="3">Windows XP</option> 
   </optgroup> 

</select>


<select name="ClasificacionWvista" id="ClasificacionWvista" size=9 id="Vista">
   <option selected value="0"> Elige una opción </option>
     <optgroup label="Microsoft" id="grupo_1">
       <option value="1">Windows Vista Starter</option> 
       <option value="2">Windows Vista Home Basic</option> 
       <option value="3">Windows Vista Home Premium</option>
       <option value="1">Windows Vista Business</option> 
       <option value="2">Windows Vista Ultimate</option> 
       <option value="3">Windows Vista Enterprise</option> 
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Microsoft" id="grupo_2"> 
       <option value="1">Starter</option> 
       <option value="2">Home Basic</option> 
       <option value="3">Professiona</option>
       <option value="2">Ultimate</option> 
       <option value="3">Enterprise</option> 
   </optgroup> 
</select>
```

**Ejemplo con jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#SistemasOperativos").change(function(){
    var valor = $(this).val();
    
    $("#ClasificacionWvista optgroup").css('display', 'none');
    $("#grupo_" + valor).css('display', 'block');
  })
})
```

```css
#ClasificacionWvista optgroup{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="SistemasOperativos" id="SistemasOperativos" size=9 id="OS" >
   <option selected value="0"> Elige una opción </option>
       <optgroup label="Microsoft"> 
       <option value="1">Windows Vista</option> 
       <option value="2">Windows 7</option> 
       <option value="3">Windows XP</option> 
   </optgroup> 

</select>


<select name="ClasificacionWvista" id="ClasificacionWvista" size=9 id="Vista">
   <option selected value="0"> Elige una opción </option>
     <optgroup label="Microsoft" id="grupo_1">
       <option value="1">Windows Vista Starter</option> 
       <option value="2">Windows Vista Home Basic</option> 
       <option value="3">Windows Vista Home Premium</option>
       <option value="1">Windows Vista Business</option> 
       <option value="2">Windows Vista Ultimate</option> 
       <option value="3">Windows Vista Enterprise</option> 
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Microsoft" id="grupo_2"> 
       <option value="1">Starter</option> 
       <option value="2">Home Basic</option> 
       <option value="3">Professiona</option>
       <option value="2">Ultimate</option> 
       <option value="3">Enterprise</option> 
   </optgroup> 
</select>
```